# Doing a shortest job first algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to simulate shortest job first technique of os using javascript, given jobs/processes, arrival time and burst time:

Checkout this link : [Shortest Job First - Concept](http://guptapreeti.blogspot.com/2012/03/example-of-preemptive-sjf.html). Now I have an array:

```
var arr = [
    {
        "job": "j4",
        "at": 0,
        "bt": 8
    },
    {
        "job": "j2",
        "at": 2,
        "bt": 4
    },
    {
        "job": "j3",
        "at": 2,
        "bt": 5
    },
    {
        "job": "j5",
        "at": 6,
        "bt": 4
    },
    {
        "job": "j1",
        "at": 8,
        "bt": 3
    }
];
```

And I wanted to create a new array containing objects of processes . .

e.g

```
[
   {"job": "j4", "range" : "0-2"},
   {"job": "j2", "range" : "2-6"},
   {"job": "j5", "range" : "6-10"},
   {"job": "j1", "range" : "10-13"},
   {"job": "j3", "range" : "13-18"},
   {"job": "j4", "range" : "18-24"}
]
```

so I tried doing it, but I'm super stuck and nowhere near what I want to achieve.

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   var temp = [];
    for(j = arr[i].at; j < arr[i].bt; j++) {
        var clone = arr.slice(0);
        var arrived = clone.splice(0, i).filter(function( obj ) {
            return obj.at == j;
        });
        var shorter = arr[i];
        for(k = 0; k < arrived.length; k++) {
            if(arrived[k].bt < arr[i].bt) {
                shorter = arrived[k];
                arr[i].bt - (j - arr[i].at);
            }
        }
        if(shorter != arr[i]) {
            j = arr[i].bt;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
    replaced the new array values with the real values if solved

```
Time Process
 0     j4(8)
 1 
 2     j4(6), j2`(4), j3(5)
 ...
 6     j4(6), j3(5), j5(4)         ::: j2 done
 7
 8     j5`(2), j4(6), j3(5), j1(3)
 9
 10                                ::: j5 done
 ...
 13                                ::: j1 done
 ...
 18                                ::: j3 done
 ...
 24                                ::: j4 done


so the new array will be

[
   {"job": "j4", "range" : "0-2"},
   {"job": "j2", "range" : "2-6"},
   {"job": "j5", "range" : "6-10"},
   {"job": "j1", "range" : "10-13"},
   {"job": "j3", "range" : "13-18"},
   {"job": "j4", "range" : "18-24"}
]
```

Comment: UM, you "new array" does not match the data

Comment: haha, yeah, that was just a random value, jeez, i'll solve it then :D sorry

Comment: I don't think a simple sort of the array will do what the op wants. Since the arrival time simulates the time at which a process is inserted, it needs to have it's burst time analysed and resources allocated to it until a process with a shorter burst time is introduced.

Comment: updated the question and simulated it by time and process :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working SJF example I've put together in JS. I've used jQuery to get data from the master array as it was mentioned in the tag. An active object is compared to a queue and elements are shifted in and out of the queue as needed and running time is added to a final array. Hope this example helps you out in getting your code working.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/R3Z2v/2/)

```
var active = undefined,
    queue = [],
    final = [],
    totalBurst = 0;

// Get the total burst time
$.map(arr, function(job, index) {
    // Add a run time variable to 
    job.runTime = job.bt;
    totalBurst += job.bt + job.at;
});

// This loop simulates time
for (var i = 0; i < totalBurst; i+=1) {
    if (typeof active === 'object') {
        active.runTime -= 1;

        if (active.runTime < 1) {
            final.push({ job : active.job, start : active.start, end : i});
            active = undefined;
        }
    }

    // Get array of jobs recieved at this time signature
    var toProcess,
        jobs = $.grep(arr, function(job, index) {
            return job.at === i;
        });

    // Merge new jobs into queue
    queue = queue.concat(jobs);    
    // Sort the queue
    queue.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.bt < b.bt ? -1 : 1;
    });

    // Get the job to process next
    toProcess = queue.splice(0,1)[0];

    if (typeof toProcess !== 'undefined') {
        // Process active job
        if (typeof active === 'undefined' && typeof toProcess !== 'undefined') {
            // Automatically start the first job in the queue
            toProcess.start = i;
            active = toProcess;
        } else if( typeof toProcess !== 'undefined' && active.bt > toProcess.bt ) {
            // Push active time to final array
            final.push({ job : active.job, start : active.start, end : i});
            // If active still has time to run add it to queue
            if (active.runTime > 0) {
                queue.push(active);
            }

            // Create new active process
            toProcess.start = i;
            active = toProcess;
        } else if( typeof toProcess !== 'undefined') {
            // Otherwise we still have an active process
            // Push the toProcess back on the queue
            queue.push(toProcess);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: that's really cool, you really put effort on your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to sort them by `bt`, shortest to longest, then this will do it...

```
var arr = [
    {
        "job": "j4",
        "at": 0,
        "bt": 8
    },
    {
        "job": "j2",
        "at": 2,
        "bt": 4
    },
    {
        "job": "j3",
        "at": 2,
        "bt": 5
    },
    {
        "job": "j5",
        "at": 6,
        "bt": 4
    },
    {
        "job": "j1",
        "at": 3,
        "bt": 3
    }
];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.bt > b.bt;
});
```

Comment: uhm, do you know sjf?

Comment: No, I just looked at your link and figure that you'd want sorting by burst time, if you wanted the shortest first.